# How to create Esri Flex Geometry from WKT

Tags: geometry, arcgis-flex-api, well-known-text

I am working with Esri flex 2.3 API, I am also using [Abode BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) for server side binding. I am sending a geometry as WKT from server into my flex client and I am looking for a way to convert the string into a flex geometry so that i can make a Graphic object and add to Feature Layer! or do I have to write a parser myself to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, why not just format to ESRI's JSON format - which is very similar to GeoJSON?  So, the workflow would look something like:

```
ON SERVER
1.  Convert geometry to GeoJSON
2.  Convert GeoJSON to ESRI JSON

ON CLIENT
3.  Create feature set by FeatureSet.fromJSON()
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither ActionScript3 nor the Flex framework offer "raw" geometry objects beyond the basic `Point()` class. In other words, there are no `Line()` or `Polygon()` classes, much less `MultiLine()` or `MultiPolygon()` classes. I'm personally not aware of a 3rd-party library that will take you from WKT right into ESRI-proprietary geometry objects.

With that said, I believe the bottom line is this: *You will still have to [adapt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) your inputs --be they WKT from your database, or conversions out of a 3rd-party libary --into the required ESRI proprietary geometry objects before you can expect to push them into an ESRI Feature Layer object*.

On the bright side, it's not difficult to get your head around the Well Known Text geometry formats. As such, I encourage you to perceive the task of writing a class to perform your WKT to ESRI geom conversions as a "fun escape" from your normal day-to-day tasks. :)

Here's a thought: Could you start such a project and release it on code.google as a 3rd-party lib so other ActionScripters could quickly and painlessly add such support to their ESRI Flex viewers?? Be warned that I have given the legality of this zero-consideration. :p

**[Edit]** If you are looking for some related open source code to retool, I would recommend perusing the [OpenScales](http://openscales.org/) codebase for useful bits. [OpenScales has some WKT support](http://openscales.org/api/core/org/openscales/core/format/package-detail.html), plus it's already in AS3/Flex; so you could expect to reuse some of their code as a convenient springboard.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, ESRI does not provide a WKT conversion method, so you would have to write your own or try to find a 3rd party ActionScript library to do it (though it would still require modifications).  SharpMap has a WKT parser that you could use to speed up the process of rolling your own parser: [GeometryFromWKT.cs](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/91116#1376621)

As a side note, ArcObjects exposes methods to convert ArcObject geometries to WKB.